# My SATA hardrive was ejected, and is unable to be remounted due to issues

Tags: disk-utility, partition, mac-pro, repair, sata

I have a Mac Pro 2012, so it's running Mountain Lion :( but it has a few partitioned drives. I have tower 1 and tower 2. Tower 2 just recently froze my computer, this has most of my videos for editing, so losing it would be quite the shame. I restarted the computer and the tower 2 icon on the left side was gone. I tried repairing it in Disk Utility, and then also in Terminal. This is the response I'm getting from my trusty ole Apple:

```
Last login: Tue Sep 13 18:34:11 on ttys001
DAJ-ROMMs-Mac-Pro:~ andrew$ diskutil repairDisk /dev/disk1 
Repairing the partition map might erase disk1s1, proceed? (y/N) y 
Started partition map repair on disk1 
Checking prerequisites
Checking the partition list
Problems were encountered during repair of the partition map 
Error: -69770: Partition map check failed because no slices were found
```

I've tried a lot of other things, like redownload the OS, and disabling spotlight through the terminal. I always end up on this response. I would really like to continue my editing, so if this rings a bell for anyone, I'd be forever grateful.

```
Last login: Wed Sep 14 14:03:44 on ttys000
sudo gpt -r show /dev/disk1
      start        size  index  contents
         0           1         PMBR
         1           1         Pri GPT header
         2          32         Pri GPT table
        34           6         
        40      409600      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
    409640  1953115495         
1953525135          32         Sec GPT table
1953525167           1         Sec GPT header
gpt show: /dev/disk2: Suspicious MBR at sector 0
     start        size  index  contents
         0           1         MBR
         1           1         Pri GPT header
         2          32         Pri GPT table
        34      411614         
    411648  1953112064      2  GPT part - EBD0A0A2-B9E5-4433-87C0-68B6B72699C7
1953523712        1423         
1953525135          32         Sec GPT table
1953525167           1         Sec GPT header
```

Comment: Done! that looks a little more promising

Comment: You should first enter `diskutil list`. The command lists all available hard drives and their partitions. One volume should have the name tower 2. If the volume name is missing and only tower1 is visible you have to determine the bogus volume/device by the exclusion principle: E.g having installed 3 hard drives: one with 500 GB and two with 1 TB and you are missing a 1 TB volume this excludes the 500 GB drive (probably disk0).

Comment: With 2 x 1TB drives left, one shows the volume name *tower 1* (e.g with the device name disk2) and the other one shows nothing you can deduce that *tower 2* was on the only possible device name left: disk1. Entering in Terminal `sudo gpt -r show disk<X>` then means replace <X>  either by 1 or 2. So the resulting command is then `sudo gpt -r show disk1` **or** `sudo gpt -r show disk2`.

Comment: Just for fun, why are you running Mountain Lion?

Comment: I got this response when I input all of that. (Thank you by the way. This is unbelievable help you're giving. It truly means a lot.)

Comment: Last login: Fri Sep 16 21:06:42 on ttys001
DAJ-ROMMs-Mac-Pro:~ andrewrommelfanger$ sudo gpt add
usage: gpt add [-b lba] [-i index] [-s lba] [-t uuid] device ...
DAJ-ROMMs-Mac-Pro:~ andrewrommelfanger$ sudo gpt add -i number -b number -s number -t type diskX
usage: gpt add [-b lba] [-i index] [-s lba] [-t uuid] device ...
DAJ-ROMMs-Mac-Pro:~ andrewrommelfanger$ sudo gpt add -2 -b 409640 -s 1952443704 -t 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC /dev/disk1
gpt: illegal option -- 2
usage: gpt add [-b lba] [-i index] [-s lba] [-t uuid] device ...
DAJ-ROMMs-Mac-Pro:~ andrewrommelfanger$

Comment: Suspicious MBR eh? This is the result from ur entry                                                                               gpt show: disk2: Suspicious MBR at sector 0
       start        size  index  contents
           0           1         MBR
           1           1         Pri GPT header
           2          32         Pri GPT table
          34      411614         
      411648  1953112064      2  GPT part - EBD0A0A2-B9E5-4433-87C0-68B6B72699C7
  1953523712        1423         
  1953525135          32         Sec GPT table
  1953525167           1         Sec GPT header

Comment: I am unfortunately forced to have mountain lion. I have a 2012 Mac Pro, just before they gave it the capability of updated further. So I'm stuck. Im pretty sure this is what caused it all. I tried to partition with bootcamp to try and get windows split on my mac. I've had issues ever since, just remembering this, hope that helps! Thanks

Comment: Hey did you see my answer? Sorry, I'm just on a bit of a deadline :/ Thanks though! @klanomath

Comment: @AndrewRommelfanger If you don't add an (at)klanomath I won't get a notification so I didn't see your comments starting at Sep, 17th. Please convert your comments to addendums/edits in your question because it's difficult to read them if they aren't formatted properly.

Comment: i just put that answer in the intial question, ill start dating and timing them if that helps. @klanomath

Comment: Hey sorry, I feel like i've made a mess of this haha. I'm not sure why my @ aren't tagging your name. Anyway, where ever we are, what next? :) @klanomath

Comment: @AndrewRommelfanger Did you execute the `sudo hexdump ...` thingy in my answer?

Answer (score 1):

To determine what's wrong with your hard drives or volumes you first have to get an overview. The best tools to get this are `diskutil` and `gpt` – both command line tools which have to be executed in Terminal.app.

Open Terminal.app and enter:

```
diskutil list
```

To execute a command you always have to enter the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

The command above will yield something like this (depending on the number of disks in your Mac):

```
/dev/disk0
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.1 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD            499.2 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
/dev/disk1
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk1
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk1s1
/dev/disk2
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk2
   2:       Microsoft Basic Data tower 1                 1.0 TB     disk2s2
```

The example shows the following:

- disk0 is your system drive containing an EFI partition (disk0s1), your main system volume "Macintosh HD" (disk0s2)  and a recovery volume (disk0s3). All partitions sizes (0.2 GB + 499 GB + 0.7 GB) add up to the total size of the disk (500 GB)
- disk1 is a 1 TB drive only containing an EFI with a size of 200 MB and with 999.8 GB empty space
- disk2 is a 1 TB drive containing one 1 TB volume probably formatted to FAT32, ExFAT or NTFS

Now one can deduce that the missing volume *tower 2* once resided on disk1.

**After a reboot the disk identifiers of the second and the third disk may be exchanged! So always execute `diskutil list` before manipulating partition tables!**

To get a closer look on disk1 use `gpt`:

```
sudo gpt -r show /dev/disk1
```

This will reveal:

```
      start        size  index  contents
         0           1         PMBR
         1           1         Pri GPT header
         2          32         Pri GPT table
        34           6         
        40      409600      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
    409640  1953115495         
1953525135          32         Sec GPT table
1953525167           1         Sec GPT header
```

This means:

- The disk has a GUID partition table (GPT)
- The first partition (index = 1) is an EFI type partition (C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B), starting at block 40 and with a size of of 409600 blocks (~209.7 MB)
- Starting at block 409640 1953115495 blocks (~1 TB) of the disk are not allocated to a partition.

You can assume that your "lost" partition (with the volume name *tower 2*) once resided here.

After adding a partition it has to be formatted and a file system has to be created. The file system may be (beyond others): HFS+, ExFAT or NTFS

If you know the previous file system you can continue restoring a partition. If you don't know the file system you can determine it by searching for typical file system headers.

To determine a previous HFSJ volume use:

```
sudo hexdump /dev/disk1 | grep "48 46 53 4a"
```

This will search for the string "HFSJ" on your raw disk. After getting the first results simply enter <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> to abort the command.

On your type of disk you should get the following results:

```
c805400 48 2b 00 04 80 00 20 00 48 46 53 4a 00 00 01 ff
ca13e00 48 2b 00 04 80 00 20 00 48 46 53 4a 00 00 01 ff
ca40e00 48 2b 00 04 80 00 20 00 48 46 53 4a 00 00 01 ff
...
```

Here the important line is the first one: `c805400 48 2b 00 04 80 00 20 00 48 46 53 4a 00 00 01 ff` with c805400 being the offset in hex. Converted with a [hex2dec service](http://www.binaryhexconverter.com/hex-to-decimal-converter) this means an offset of Byte 209736704 (dividing this by 512 Bytes/block, the result is equal to block 409642). Typically the 3rd block of an HFSJ volume contains the string "HFSJ". So you have found the beginning of an HFSJ volume: block 409640 (*BlockF*).

The end of an HFSJ volume can be found accordingly because the 3rd last block contains the last HFSJ occurrence:

```
sudo hexdump -s 930g /dev/disk1 | grep "48 46 53 4a"
```

The option -s means: Skip offset bytes from the beginning of the input.

With the last offset (and doing the math like above) you can determine the last block (*BlockL)* of the previous HFSJ volume by simply adding 2 blocks. The size of the HFSJ volume is then (BlockL-BlockF).

With all necessary data gathered you can now try to restore the lost volume *tower 2* with the `sudo gpt add ...` command.

To add a partition entry you have to execute:

```
sudo gpt add -i number -b number -s number -t type diskX
```

with

- -i index number
- -b number of the first block
- -s size in blocks
- -t partition type

I don't know neither the first offset nor the second offset of your volume *tower 2*, but the command below may work and the entered sizes are probable defaults:

```
sudo gpt add -2 -b 409640 -s 1952443704 -t 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC /dev/disk1
```

After adding this entry in the partition table the volume should be mounted automatically.

Check the disk and the volume with:

```
diskutil verifyDisk disk1
diskutil verifyVolume disk1s2
```

If a repair is necessary use the "prefix" repair instead of verify!

---

If you have any questions or can't find the string "HFSJ" please add a comment with *@klanomath*!

Comment: How does the case look like with APFS? @klanomath